# removing string shorter than length 2 using regular expression

Tags: java, regex

i have text file consisting of sequences. my text file look like

- 1,48 15
- 1 15,32
- 1 15,32,45
- 1,45 15,32

I want to remove that string which consist of length less than 2 before space. for eg. second and third sequence consists of only 1 number before space, i want to discard that strings but first and last sequence consist of 2 numbers, those will stay.
desired output will be :

- 1,48 15
- 1,45 15,32

I have tried this expression

```
s1.replaceAll("\\b[\\w']{1}\\b", "")
```

but my output look like

- ,48 15
- 15,32
- 15,32,45
- ,45 15,32

Comment: Maybe `s1.replaceAll("(?m)^\\d\\s.*\r?\n?", "")` is enough?

Comment: Thanks.it worked but sequence like 712 722 still there

Comment: Acc. to your requirements, `712 722` should stay. I am more interested if you want to remove lines with `123 23 1 456` because of `1` inside. I'd suggest `^(?:[\\d ,]+ )?\\d(?: [\\d ,]*+(?:\n|$))` then

Comment: sorry but 712 is a single number . i.e less than 2 ..

Comment: Ok, I see. You mean 1 number on a line, right? Try [`s1.replaceAll("(?m)^\\d+\\s.*\r?\n?", "")`](https://regex101.com/r/sO9wU2/2). If it works, I will post as an answer.

Comment: I have updated the comment above by adding `(?m)` multiline modifier.

Comment: working properly now . thanks for understanding :)

Comment: I have posted my answer with the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to remove *line* starting with one *number* (sequence of digits) before the first space, you can use

```
s1.replaceAll("(?m)^\\d+\\s.*\r?\n?", "")
```

Or (to make sure we do not match a newline, replace `\s` with `[^\S\n]`):

```
 s1.replaceAll("(?m)^\\d+[^\\S\n].*\r?\n?", "")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sO9wU2/2)

The pattern matches:

- `(?m)^` - enabling multiline mode where `^` matches the line start
- `\\d+` - one or more digits
- `\\s` - a whitespace (`[^\S\n]` matches any whitespace but a line feed)
- `.*` - any character but a newline as many as possible up to
- `\r?\n?` - one or zero `\r` followed with one or zero occurrences of `\n`.

See the [Java demo:](http://ideone.com/XknPUE)

```
String s1 = "1,48 15\n1 15,32\n1 15,32,45\n1,45 15,32";
System.out.println(s1.replaceAll("(?m)^\\d+\\s.*\r?\n?", ""));
```

**NOTE** that if you have leading whitespace that you want to ignore, use

```
^\s*\d+\s.*\r?\n?
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sO9wU2/3)

Comment: hey .i am not getting how to remove the empty lines left afterwards. i have tried doing with adding \\b. but its not working. can you help ?

Comment: There should be no empty lines. Could you please post the real line, like `String s = "783 455 444 \n34345 656465"` (use the `\`` symbols inside comments to format "code")

Comment: `String s="1 15,32,45" `

Comment: @lucy: Please [check this demo](http://ideone.com/vOgper) - no issues with whitespace or empty lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your lines using the following pattern:

```
String text = 
    "1,48 15"
        + System.getProperty("line.separator")
        + "1 15,32"
        + System.getProperty("line.separator")
        + "1 15,32,45"
        + System.getProperty("line.separator")
        + "1,45 15,32";
//                                  | multi-line pattern flag
//                                  |   | start of line
//                                  |   || one character
//                                  |   ||   | followed by space
//                                  |   ||   |  | etc.
//                                  |   ||   |  |      | replace with empty line
//                                  |   ||   |  |      | 
System.out.println(text.replaceAll("(?m)^.{1}\\s.*?$", ""));
```

**Output**

```
1,48 15


1,45 15,32
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
System.out.println(text.replaceAll("(?m)\\n^\\d\\s[^\\n]+", ""));
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iO1jE0/1)

output:

```
1,48 15
1,45 15,32
```

it should also remove empty lines.